# Doesn't Conservation of angular momentum contradict the need for a centripetal force?

Tags: angular-momentum, centripetal-force

If an object is rotating in space, then there has to be a centripetal force acting upon it to constantly change its direction. I thought if an object begins to rotate in space, it would slow down since there is no centripetal force that keeps it changing direction, but that is contradictory to the conservation of angular momentum law.

Comment: What makes you think that angular momentum is not conserved for an object moving linearly?

Comment: Rotation and revolution are different terms. To rotate generally means to rotate about your own axis, while revolving means revolving around another body. Could you clarify what you mean?

Comment: Do you mean, like (1) A spinning top or (2)? A  an object attached to a rope spinning aroun the other endpoint .

Comment: There is no reason to upvote, but ...  Why downvote someone who is
confused and is asking for clarification?  He simply states what he
believes he understood, and is obviously aware he is making
mistakes. He is not asserting anything. Is it that he should first
apologize for not knowing or not understanding?

Comment: @Dimension10 Why do you ask ? The only significant difference I can see is only a linguistic concern.

Comment: @babou: Nope,  I'm asking whether it was like getting the rope cut or just stop putting a force on it.

Comment: @Dimension10 I am not sure I am following you. What is the difference ? Actually, the OP cannot be
considering a spinning top, unless he spins it fast enough to explode
it with centrifugal force. I think he understood that the centripetal
force is the source of the angular momentum, hence of the
rotation. For me, this is not a bad question since I was myself a bit
confused, in a much different way. So I built an example (last part of my far too long
answer) that has angular momentum and no centripetal force.

Comment: @babou: What I thought: A brick/monkey is tied to a rope and someone is spinning the rope around, then someone chops the rope. What it really means: A spinning top/monkey attached to a rope, the rope is not cut, but a force is no longer applied.   Then, the answer is obvious as    other answers say.

Answer (score 4):

The centripetal force may change the *direction*, but since it's always orthogonal to the moving direction it will never change the absolute momentum / energy.

> I thought if an object begins to rotate in space

An object never *begins* to rotate in space. Nor does a rotating object slow down. If there is no centripetal force, then it just *won't* rotate but fly apart, each particle tangetial to its "rotation" orbit. This will indeed look like a slowdown if you concentrate on *angular speed* – but after all that is not a conserved quantity. It's angular *momentum* that is conserved, with or without centripetal force, and obviously also for a linearly moving object (or multiple such objects):

$$
  \mathbf{r}(t) = \mathbf{r}_0 + \mathbf{v}\cdot t
$$
$$
  \implies  \dot{\mathbf{r}}(t) \equiv \mathbf{v}
$$
So
$$
  \frac{\mathbf{L}(t)}{m} 
     = \mathbf{r}(t) \times \dot{\mathbf{r}}(t)
     = (\mathbf{r}_0 + \mathbf{v}\cdot t) \times \mathbf{v}
     = \mathbf{r}_0\times \mathbf{v} + t\cdot \underbrace{\mathbf{v}\! \times\! \mathbf{v}}_{=0}
     = \mathbf{r}_0\times \mathbf{v}.
$$
Which is constant.

Comment: Let me rephrase my question: If a torque is applied on an astronaut so that he beggins to rotate, where does the centripetal force come from that keeps him rotating? I understand for example that gravity acts as  the centripetal force on the moon to keep it rotating around earth.

Comment: Well, the astronaut certainly has an endoskeleton that is able to excert some centripetal force on his limbs! But this force is not what "keeps him rotating", it's what **keeps him in one piece**. What keeps him rotating is simply inertia. Depending on how you look at it, gravity also doesn't keep the moon rotating, it rather keeps it from flying away.

Answer (score 2):

**Content**

- Brief answer
- A first explanation
- Reply to Mark Mitchison
- The case of the disappearing angular momentum

The last part may be read directly and explains angular momentum conservation on a simple example.

*The answer has been modified following Mark Mitchison's comments*

**Brief answer**

Angular momentum exists independently of any centripetal force. The
point to understand is that with any motion, a moving mass has an
angular momentum with respect to any point in space you care to
choose as center. If the torque of all forces on that mass with
respect to that center point is zero, then the angular momentum does
not change for that center. That is conservation of angular momentum.

When an appropriate (centripetal) force is applied orthogonally to the
trajectory so that the mass goes into a rotation around a specific
center, the angular momentum with respect to that center does not
change because the torque of that force is zero for that center. But
the angular momentum changes for all other points as they are not aligned (except in
passing) with the center of rotation and the moving mass. So the role
of the centripetal force is to enforce rotation around one specific
center. It happens to be such that angular momentum is conserved with
respect to that center.

There is no contradiction.

**A first explanation**

The author of the question states quite correctly that the role of the centripetal force is to
keep changing the direction of motion of each fragment of the
rotating/revolving body. This centripetal force is orthogonal to the
motion, thus never contributes to its speed, only to its direction.
So the centripetal force preserve the rotating aspect of motion, not motion itself. If it ceases, motion persist, but becomes linear. So the angular momentum seems gone: more on this below in "the case of the disappearing angular momentum".

The centripetal force can have many sources. For a solid body rotating
on itself, it is the internal cohesion forces that keep the molecules
together and prevent them from flying apart.

If it is a weight at the end of a rope (ever watched the hammer throw
at the olympics) being rotated by a person, it is the rope pulling on
the weight that transmit the centripetal force, has long as the person
can keep holding it (he can feel the force in his arms).  Note that
when the person lets go, the weight will fly off a tangent, in a
straight line (well, on Earth,  it will curve to the ground). Note also that letting go may unbalance the thrower, if the weight is large enough.

If it is a planet in space, the centripetal force is provided by
gravity from the sun. Remove the sun, and the planet will fly off a tangent (this is only a - not very good - thought experiment).

A satellite around Earth will also use Earth gravity as a centripetal force.
But you could have a similar trajectory in deep space, without a
planet providing the centripetal force: you just replace the
gravitation by a push from a rocket engine, slowly rotating the
orientation of the push so that it stays orthogonal to motion.

Centripetal force can be produced by a normal force, a reaction force
from a circular support, as for motorbikes rotating inside a sphere 
([Motorcycle Sphere Cage Stunt](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6QAspo38GI0))

I am sure there is more.

Now, what seems really preserved is momentum, so that When an object is rotating
and kept in that rotation, preservation of momentum becomes
preservation of angular momentum. We first looks at this, and learn better afterwards.

If for some reason the centripetal force ceases to act, the momentum
seems preserved in a in linear momentum. A good example is a car
with linear momentum and kinetic energy entering a loop.The linear momentum (apparently) induces angular momentum while the
car stays bound to the circular motion by the loop.
([Fifth Gear Loop the Loop](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wiZoVAZGgsw)).
Actually this would be a better example in space, because on Earth
there is a complication coming from the fact that going up the loop
has to fight gravity, which does alter speed and
momentum. (I do what I can)

Another example is the weight on a string. The angular momentum seems
to disappears, leaving only the linear momentum when you let go of the
string, thus removing the centripetal force.
It can be deadly, as [David taught Goliath](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_and_Goliath).

Actually, what I said above is only an approximation, which seems to work when we consider
that whatever provides the centripetal force is some kind of immovable
reference, like earth for a ball. In reality, there is always a
reaction on whatever provides the centripetal force, or ceases to
provide it (as the hammer thrower), so that **the angular momentum is
always preserved**, as remarked by Mark Mitchison and as discussed below
in my reply to him, and then in a more detailed explanation of a very simple case.

**Reply to  Mark Mitchison.**

I am replying here to Mark Mitchison's comment, as I do not like to
leave an error in an answer, if I can help it. I do thank Mark
Mitchison for making me think further about it (I am not a physicist)
so that I could correct this answer.

I was very careless in my original answer which said, in the car loop
example, that when "*entering a loop [...] the momentum becomes
angular momentum, to become linear momentum again when exiting*". And
again in the following sentence stating that the angular momentum of
the weight "*changes into linear momentum*" when you let go of the rope.

Indeed, as Mark Mitchison remarks, angular momentum and linear
momentum are different physical quantities. However they are not completely
unrelated quantities. Angular momentum is to linear momentum what a
torque is to a force. And, with appropriate devices, force can be apparently
"changed" into torque, and conversely, following precise laws. We do
that all the time. This is actually visible in the point mass momentum
formula $L = (mv)r$ where $mv$ is the momentum of the mass $m$ with speed $v$ and $L$ its angular momentum with respect to a rotation axis at distance
$r$. (More precisely, $r$ and $mv$ should be vectors, and $L$ their cross product.)

My intuition was that what is preserved is linear momentum, and that
the preservation of angular momentum can be derived as a consequence,
at least in classical mechanics. I also thought that the converse
might be possible too. Looking a bit on the web, I do realize that it
must be a bit more subtle, both being apparently faces of the same inertial
coin. But my current understanding stops here.

Still, my interest on this site is, to a large extent, to be able to
explain things with as little math as possible, and some
back-of-the-envelope calculations. Math is of course essential, but I
never took a formula for an understanding.

So I will try to explain here where the angular momentum goes when the
centripetal force disappear.

[image]

**The case of the disappearing angular momentum**

Angular momentum is like corpses in detective novels: you may not find
them, but they have to be somewhere.

Lets take a simple murder case: it is the case of two equal point
masses ($m$ each) tied by a massless rope of length $2r$, turning in
freefall (no external forces) with a linear speed $v$. The rope is
there to provide the centripetal force, which for each mass is the
centrifugal force of the other transmitted by the rope. The two masses turn on a circle, the
rope being a rotating diameter of the circle.

The linear momentum of each mass is $mv$, and its angular momentum is
$(mv)r$. The total angular momentum is thus $2(mv)r$.

This is not really much different from David rotating his sling,
except for the fact that David is heavier than his stones.

Now we cut the rope, letting the two point masses fly of
the tangents, which are two parallel lines at a distance $2r$. There
is only linear motion, so it seems that the angular momentum has
disappeared. Let's find it.

You must first note that since there are no external forces on the
system, its center of mass will not move. The masses fly away in
opposite directions and at the same speed. Now, you may notice also
that the trajectory of each is on a straight line, which is at distance $r$
from the center of mass (on two opposite sides).

Let O be the center of mass, A and A' the positions of the masses on
the circle at time 0 when the rope is cut, and B and B' their position
at some time $\theta$ later. Consider the linear momentum vector $mv$
on AB.  It project as a vector $mv_t$ on the perpendicular to the line
0B in B, which forms with the vector $mv$ on AB a triangle similar to
OAB. Let $R$ be the distance between O and B. It is easy to show from
relations in similar triangles that $R(mv_t)=r(mv)$.

In other words, the mass in B (and same for B') still has the same
angular momentum with respect to the center of mass.

Note that the line BB' between the masses is still a diameter that
rotates ever more slowly so as to accomodate straight motion of both
masses.

- *More generally, For any chosen point in space, the line connecting this point to a moving mass will thus rotate according to the angular momentum of the mass with respect to the point considered and its moment of inertia for that point. This momentum is invariant in the absence of force applied to the mass. Such a force defines a corresponding torque with respect to the center of rotation considered, which can be applied taking into account to the moment of inertia of the mass for that same center.*

Indeed, there was another invisible massless rope between the 2 masses,
of length $2R$. So at time $\theta$, this new rope is taut, and the
radial components of the two linear momentums, on line BB', cancel out
providing for each mass a new centripetal force. What is left is the two
projections $R(mv_t)$ for each mass, opposite and orthogonal to the
line BOB'.

Then the two masses will start rotating again at distance $R$ around
the common center of mass, with the same angular momentum as before,
as we have computed. The speed will be slower, compensated in inverse
proportion by a longer radius.

Our corpse was not dead, after all.

This shows that angular momentum is preserved on its own, but is
related to linear momentum, at least in classical mechanics.

(Note that my use of vectors is a bit loose, since angular momentum is a vector cross product).

*Sorry for being so long. I write also for myself. I found this work very fruitful as it lead me to another question: [What is the difference between translation and rotation?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/75047/)*

Comment: As tempting as it is to think of angular momentum as "linear momentum going round in a circle", this is wrong. They are physically different quantities. Consider the car going round the loop at constant speed. If you actually calculate the car's angular momentum before, during and after the loop you will find that it is always the *same*, it doesn't change. So it is not linear momentum "becoming" angular momentum. (You need to use the proper vectorial definition of angular momentum $\mathbf{L} = \mathbf{r}\times\mathbf{p}$ to show this.) (contd.)

Comment: Obviously the car's linear momentum does change as its direction of motion changes round the loop. But momentum is conserved, so where does it go? The answer is that the car  pushes on (and is pushed by) the loop as it changes direction. The initial linear momentum lost by the car is thus imparted to whatever the loop is attached to, eg the Earth. (contd.)

Comment: If the car is moving at constant speed, then the linear momentum lost (gained) by the car at each point is gained (lost) again when the car passes over the antipodal point of the loop. So the linear momenta of both car and Earth return to their initial values in this idealised case.

Comment: @MarkMitchison Thanks a lot for correcting my naive intuition. Is this better now?

Comment: Your demonstration of the conservation of angular momentum for the rotating masses is fine. I would still be careful though, it is better to say that angular and linear momentum are **analogous** rather than "dependent". They are "two sides of the same coin" only in that they are both kinds of inertia. They are the independently conserved charges associated with the spatial symmetries of our universe, i.e. translations (linear momentum) and rotations (angular momentum). I recommend that you look up [Noether's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noether's_theorem) for a deeper understanding

Comment: Thanks. I will attempt to look up Noether's theorem. While I have some
vague understanding of what you mean, it does bother me to see angular
and linear momentums as simply analogous. Maybe it is because straight
lines are just "very big" circles :). Is there a concept of projective
cosmology ? :) I am only using very old memories, while my competence
is gone.

Comment: It also - still - bothers me somewhat, but you learn to live with it. I think our primitive "monkey" intuition respects the concept of inertia more than the distinction between rotation and translation, which can sometimes seem artificial. But mathematically they are independent quantities, and physically have quite different roles. For example, constant motion in a straight line is empirically equivalent to no motion: there is no "absolute" linear motion, only relative. However, constant rotation has observable consequences, so the concept of "absolute" rotational motion is meaningful.

Comment: @MarkMitchison I find this discussion most interesting. Still
wondering on some points. In your initial criticism, you asserted
that my view of momentum conservation was wrong. However I do not see
how you can sustain this assertion. Do you have a way to prove it, can
it be shown experimentally ?  I am of course aware that considering the
outside artifacts as non movable was an approximation, which I think
is quite common. I was also aware of the dimensional difference. But
that was not your issue, as far as I can tell. Two quantities may be
dependent without having the same dimension.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what criticism you are referring to. As far as I remember, my original issue was the implication that linear and angular momentum are interconvertible. This statement contradicts the laws of motion (or quantum mechanics) which of course are empirically proven.

Comment: @MarkMitchison Yes. I fully agree that, as originally stated [my
answer](http://physics.stackexchange.com/revisions/74743/2) was at
least misleading, particularly when intended for someone who has
trouble understanding angular momentum. But the reasonning that I
intended intuitively can be [precisely
formalized](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/75641#75830),
and that has kept me busy recently. In this sense, angular momentum is
"linear momentum going round in a circle".
What bothers me is that I cannot identify what makes angular momentum
a phenomenon distinct from linear momentum.