# Coordinate System vs. Angular Properties vs. Centroid

Tags: homework-and-exercises, angular-momentum, rotational-dynamics, torque, rigid-body-dynamics

Please help me check my understanding related to the rotational motion of a 3D rigid body after reading some Physics textbooks and googling for some more materials (e.g., [Wikipedia's Torque](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torque), [Wikipedia's Moment of Inertia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment_of_inertia)).

The following points are to be checked against a situation where the rotational motion of a 3D rigid body happens about a single rotation axis in an inertial Cartesian coordinate system where the z-axis is taken to be the rotation axis but the origin $O$ of the coordinate system is **not** necessarily on the centroid of the 3D rigid body and can even be **outside** the 3D rigid body:

1. Each particle in the rigid body has $\vec{v} = \vec{\omega} \times \vec{r}$ where $\vec{r}$ is the position vector of the particle with respect to the origin $O$, and therefore, the speed of each particle depends on the choice of origin $O$.
2. With respect to $O$, the moment of force $\vec{\tau}$ and the angular momentum change $d\vec{L}$ about the z-axis have the same directions.
3. With respect to $O$, the angular acceleration $\vec{\alpha}$ and the angular velocity change $d\vec{\omega}$ about the z-axis have the same directions.
4. Moment of inertia $I$ is always calculated with respect to z-axis, not the centroid of the rigid body, such that the $s$ in $\int s^2 dm$ is always the distance between a point mass in the rigid body and z-axis.
5. Angular momentum of each particle in the rigid body $\vec{L} = \vec{r}\times\vec{p}$ where $\vec{r}$ is the position vector of $\vec{p}$ with respect to the origin $O$ (i.e., $||\vec{r}||$ is **not** the distance between $\vec{p}$ and z-axis), and therefore, the direction of $\vec{L}$ may be different from $\vec{\omega}$.
6. Total angular momentum of the rigid body is then $\sum \vec{L} = I \vec{\omega}$, and therefore, the direction of $\sum \vec{L}$ is the same as $\vec{\omega}$.
7. The torque experienced by each particle in the rigid body $\vec{\tau} = \vec{r}\times\vec{F}$ where $\vec{r}$ is the position vector of $\vec{F}$ with respect to the origin $O$ (i.e., $||\vec{r}||$ is **not** the distance between $\vec{F}$ and z-axis), and therefore, the direction of $\vec{\tau}$ may be different from $\vec{\omega}$.
8. The total torque experienced by the rigid body is then $\sum \vec{\tau} = I \vec{\alpha}$, and therefore, the direction of $\sum \vec{\tau}$ is the same as $\vec{\alpha}$.
9. The torque experienced by each particle in the rigid body is related to each particle's angular momentum rate of change $\vec{r}\times\vec{F} = \vec{\tau} = \frac{d\vec{L}}{dt} = \frac{d(\vec{r} \times \vec{p})}{dt} = m\frac{d(\vec{r} \times \vec{v})}{dt} = m\frac{d(\vec{r} \times (\vec{\omega}\times\vec{r}))}{dt} = m\frac{d((\vec{r}\cdot\vec{r}) \vec{\omega} - (\vec{r}\cdot\vec{\omega})\vec{r})}{dt}$, and therefore, for each particle the directions of $\vec{\tau}$ and $d\vec{L}$ are the same but may be different from the direction of $\vec{\omega}$.
10. The total torque experienced by the rigid body is related to the total angular momentum's rate of change $I \vec{\alpha} = \sum \vec{\tau} = \frac{d\left(\sum\vec{L}\right)}{dt} = \frac{d\left(\sum I\;\vec{\omega}\right)}{dt} = \sum I \frac{d\vec{\omega}}{dt}$, and therefore, the directions of $\vec{\alpha}$, $\sum \vec{\tau}$, $\sum d\vec{L}$, and $d\vec{\omega}$ are the same.

Any mistake? Because the rotation axis can be outside the 3D rigid body, I feel uneasy especially for Point 5 to 10.

Comment: Seems like googling using "moment of force" instead of "torque" is more useful. I found [this slide from PSU](http://engr.bd.psu.edu/rxm61/MCHT111/6-Moments%20Couples%20and%20Force%20Couple%20Systems.ppt) that says that $\tau$ is calculated by projecting all the forces onto the plane perpendicular to the rotation axis. That is also what I feel being strongly suggested in introductory Physics textbooks although I found no explicit statement as the one in the slide. I wonder why that is the case.

Comment: What I found in the introductory Physics textbooks is always along the line given by [this lecture notes from University of Rochester](http://teacher.pas.rochester.edu/phy121/lecturenotes/Chapter12/Chapter12.html): they define $\vec{\tau} = \vec{r} \times \vec{F}$ on a particle on a plane and then discuss 3D rigid bodies like a cylinder without explicitly relate how $\vec{r}$ now means with respect to the origin $O$ now that some particles in the rigid bodies are on planes that do not include the origin $O$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Check ✓ except the the speed depends on the center of rotation, not the choice of the origin. The general rule is that if the origin as velocity $\vec{v}_O$ then a point *A* located at $\vec{r}_A$ has speed $\vec{v}_A = \vec{v}_O + \vec\omega \times \vec{r}_A$. It happenstance that your origin does not move.
2. Check ✓. In general, torques and angular momental are related with $\sum \vec{\tau}_A = \frac{{\rm d}}{{\rm d}t} \vec{L}_A$ where *A* is any point on the rotating frame.
3. Check ✓. Angular velocity and acceleration is shared among all points fixed to the rotating frame. Acceleration is the time derivative of velocity $\frac{{\rm d}}{{\rm d}t}\vec{\omega} = \vec{\alpha}$.
4. Incorrect ×. Mass moment of inertia $I$ is a tensor of 6 values represented by a 3×3 matrix $$I=\begin{pmatrix} I_{xx} & I_{xy} & I_{xz} \\ I_{xy} & I_{yy} & I_{yz} \\ I_{xz} & I_{yz} & I_{zz} \end{pmatrix}$$ Some books have the cross terms negative and some positive. There is no convention of what is a positive $I_{xy} = \int x y {\rm d}m$ or $I_{xy} = \int -x y {\rm d}m$ ([ref 1](http://www.eng.auburn.edu/~marghitu/MECH2110/C_4.pdf)). Typically, this tensor (MMOI) is described on the center of mass first, along coordinates fixed to the body. So $I_{body}$ is constant. As the body rotates it has a 3×3 rotation matrix $R$ so the MMOI tensor in fixed coordinates at the center of mass is $$I_C = R I_{body} R^\top$$ with $^\top$ the matrix transpose operator. To move the MMOI tensor to a different location, like where the rotation center is (or the origin) one must apply the parallel axis theorem. This is done with $$I_O = I_C - m [\vec{r}_C] [\vec{r}_C]$$ where `[vector]` is the 3×3 skew symmetric cross product operator ([ref 2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%E2%80%93Euler_equations)) and $\vec{r}_C$ is the position of the center of mass relative to *O* in fixed coordinates.
5. Incorrect ×. Angular momentum at any point *not* at the center of mass has two components. One is the intrinsic momentum at the center of mass $I_C \vec{\omega}$ and the second the moment of linear momentum $\vec{r}_C \times m \vec{v}_C$ where $\vec{v}_C$ is the linear velocity of the center of mass. $$\vec{L}_O = I_C \vec{\omega} + \vec{r}_C \times m \vec{v}_C = I_C \vec{\omega} + \vec{r}_C \times m ( \vec{v}_O + \vec\omega \times \vec{r}_C ) \\ = \left(I_C \vec{\omega} - m \vec{r}_C \times \vec{r}_C \times \vec\omega \right) + \vec{r}_C \times m \vec{v}_O = I_O \vec\omega + \vec{r}_C \times m \vec{v}_O$$ Do you see how the parallel axis theorem is derived from the angular momentum transformation laws.
6. Incorrect ×. Because MMOI is a tensor and not a scalar the direction of $\vec{L}$ is generally *not* the same as $\vec\omega$.
7. Check ✓. Torque is vector field (varying by location) with the general law of $$\vec{\tau}_O = \vec{\tau}_A + \vec{r}_A \times \vec{F}$$ This is dual to the velocity transformation law (above on 1.), if re-arranged like $\vec{\tau}_A = \vec{\tau}_O +  \vec{F} \times \vec{r}_A $. The direction of $\vec\tau$ (at origin?) is different from $\vec\omega$ because $I_C$ is not constant (see below).
8. The general equations of motion are $$\boxed{\begin{align} \sum \vec{F} & = \frac{\rm d}{{\rm d}t} \vec{p} = m \frac{\rm d}{{\rm d}t} \vec{v}_C = m \vec{a}_C \\  \sum \vec{\tau}_C & = \frac{\rm d}{{\rm d}t}L_C = I_C \frac{\rm d}{{\rm d}t} \vec\omega + \frac{\rm d}{{\rm d}t}\left( I_C \right)  \vec\omega = I_C \vec\alpha + \vec\omega \times I_C \vec\omega \end{align} }$$ expressed at the center of mass always ([ref 3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_laws_of_motion)). Then use the transformation laws to move the torque around (like knowing that the torque component along the rotation axis is zero). In your case $\hat{z}^\top \vec{\tau}_O =0$ and $\vec{\tau}_O =\sum \vec{\tau}_C + \vec{r}_C \times \sum \vec{F}$.
9. You need to re-work the rest from the information given above.

Comment: See related post http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/95542/392 if interested in the subject.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! I really need it. So, introductory Physics textbooks simplify things in their discussions & exercises by always choosing a rotation axis that goes through the center of mass of a 3D rigid body?

Comment: Yes, 3D dynamics and kinematics are straight forward if you get all your ducks in a row, but there are a lot of ducks to account for.