# How to calculate inertia tensor of composite shape with angle?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, rotational-dynamics, rotation, moment-of-inertia

I have I have some objects assembled like this :

[image]

The inertia tensor would be :

$$I=I_1+I_2+I_3-m_1 \,\tilde{r}_{01}\,\tilde{r}_{01}-m_3\,\,\tilde{r}_{03}\,\tilde{r}_{03}$$

Where :

$$\tilde{r}_{01}=\begin{bmatrix}
   0 & -z & 0 \\
   z & 0 & 0 \\
   0 & 0 & 0 \\
 \end{bmatrix}$$

and
$$\tilde{r}_{03}=\begin{bmatrix}
   0 & +z & 0 \\
   -z & 0 & 0 \\
   0 & 0 & 0 \\
 \end{bmatrix}$$

According to [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/505273/227458).

Detailed notations [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EzMJ3.png).

But what is the inertia if -

- I rotate the planar object on the very top(everything with it) around $Z$-axis
- Just rotate the rod and sphere (except the planar object), just like a pendulum. Let angle with $X$-axis is $\alpha$ and angle with $Y$-axis is $\beta$
- Do both together

Comment: @G.Smith maybe if you take some time, you can see I asked that question. And that has an accepted answer, Why would I ask the same question ? Maybe it has something new. And yes it does, some calculation about angles . Can you help with it, please ?

Comment: The intertia tensor about which point? The yellow circle in your figure?

Comment: About the dot you can see in the planar object. @SuperCiocia

Comment: You can rotate the inertia tensor like this $I_{i}\rightarrow S^{T}I_{i}S$ S is orthonormal rotation matrix , fBut to add the inertia tensor after rotation , the coordinate systems must be parallel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The inertia tensor obeys the congruent transformation from the local coordinates to the world coordinates.

If you have a 3×3 rotation matrix $\mathbf{R}$ then you have

$$ \mathbf{I}_{\rm world} = \mathbf{R} \, \mathbf{I}_{\rm body} \mathbf{R}^\top $$

So the combined inertia would be

$$ \mathbf{I} = \mathbf{R} \, \left(\mathbf{I}_1 +\mathbf{I}_2 + \mathbf{I}_3   \right) \mathbf{R}^\top - m_1 \overline{\boldsymbol{r}}_1 \overline{\boldsymbol{r}}_1 - m_3 \overline{\boldsymbol{r}}_3 \overline{\boldsymbol{r}}_3$$

You must make sure the vectors $\boldsymbol{r}_n$ point to the center of mass in the world coordinate system *after the body is rotated*.

See also [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/385152/392) to a similar question.