# Does the axis of rotation of a rigid body depend on the frame of reference?

Tags: classical-mechanics

When studying the kinematic motion of a rigid body, angular velocity $\omega$ is a  vector that not seem to specify a unique axis of rotation... When looking at the free rigid body motion of a wheel rolling without sliding, we can talk about the wheel's rotation from the point of view of a fixed frame of reference and in that case talk about rotation about the instantaneous center of rotation (which is the contact point) or we can talk about rotation from the center of mass frame of reference and in that acase the center of rotation is the center of mass itself. From a frame of reference that is fixed with the wheel (body axes), the wheel does not rotate at all because the frame of reference rotates and every point looks stationary. Chasles theorem states that a rigid body can pass from one configuration to the next one via one of the infinite combinations of translation/rotation about any **arbitrary** point which becomes the point of rotation for that transformation. All transformations share the same $\omega$...  Does that mean that rotation is a relative concept and there is no unique, physical, axis of rotation for a rigid body? I have read about the instantaneous screw axis where the points of the rigid body with the same velocity parallel to the axis reside...
Certainly, when a free rigid body rotates while translating, maybe tumbling in some random fashion, the initial conditions (how the body starts, the forces in action) should uniquely determine the rigid body's configuration at every instant $t$ and how it kinematically moves from one configuration to the next: even if Chasles theorem states that there are infinite possible combinations (translation+rotation), the body certainly moves from its current configuration to the next configuration in a very specific way...Can anyone shine some clarity on this topic?

Comment: Would you mind refining your question into categories such as what you understand, what you are confused about etc.. it makes it much easier to address it

Comment: I am having a hard time understanding what exactly you are asking, and I consider myself an expert in rigid body kinematics and screw theory.

Comment: the apparent axis of rotation will depend on your frame of reference, same as your velocity, kinetic energy,  and many other variables

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the question.

At any instance, in any *one* coordinate frame if the position $\boldsymbol{r}_A$, velocity $\boldsymbol{v}_A$ of a point **A** in a rigid body rotating with $\boldsymbol{\omega}$ is known or measured then the location of the instantaneous rotation axis is given by the following calculation

- **Direction** (Vector) - The direction of rotation is $$ \boldsymbol{e} = \frac{ \boldsymbol{\omega} }{ \| \boldsymbol{\omega} \| }$$
- **Position** (Vector) - The point on the rotation axis closest to the coordinate frame is $$\boldsymbol{r}_{\rm COR} = \boldsymbol{r}_A + \frac{ \boldsymbol{\omega} \times \boldsymbol{v}_A} { \| \boldsymbol{\omega} \|^2 }$$
- **Magnitude** (Scalar) - The magnitude of rotation $$ \omega = \| \boldsymbol{\omega} \| $$
- **Pitch** (Scalar) - The ratio of the parallel motion (translation) along the rotation axis to the rotation magnitude $$ h = \frac{ \boldsymbol{\omega} \cdot \boldsymbol{v}_A }{ \| \boldsymbol{\omega} \|^2 } $$

  <sub>Here $\cdot$ is the vector inner product and $\times$ the vector cross product. Vector quantities are shown in **boldface**.</sub>

I can provide proof of the above if needed. So from the basis of the statements above can you comment below and rephrase./summarise your question.

---

### Equations of Motion

Equations of motion for a rigid body are derived from the time derivative of momentum. When expressed at the center of mass (Point **C**) the momentum equations are

$$ \begin{aligned} 
  \boldsymbol{p} & = m \boldsymbol{v}_C \\
  \boldsymbol{L}_C & = \mathrm{I}_C \,\boldsymbol{\omega}
\end{aligned} $$

<sub>Where $\mathbf{I}_C$ is the mass moment of inertia 3×3 tensor about the center of mass, and $\boldsymbol{v}_C$ the velocity of the center of mass.</sub>

As you can see, as expressed at the center of mass the equations are rather simple.

Now transform the above equations to an arbitrary point **A** and the above become

$$ \begin{aligned} 
  \boldsymbol{p} & = m ( \boldsymbol{v}_A - \boldsymbol{c} \times \boldsymbol{\omega}) \\
  \boldsymbol{L}_A & = \mathrm{I}_A \boldsymbol{\omega} + \boldsymbol{c} \times m  \boldsymbol{v}_A 
\end{aligned} $$

<sub>Where $\boldsymbol{c}$ is the position vector of the center of mass from the reference point **A**. Also $\mathbf{I}_A$ is the mass moment of inertia tensor at **A**.</sub>

As you can see, the level of complexity has increased significantly since now there are cross terms (linear momentum depends on $\boldsymbol{\omega}$ and angular momentum on $\boldsymbol{v}_A$

Now ask the question if resolving the equations of motion onto the *center of rotation* makes things any simpler. The answer is just marginally yes. If **A** is the center of rotation, then $\boldsymbol{v}_A = h\, \boldsymbol{\omega}$ where the scalar $h$ is the pitch. That is it. That is all the simplifies at the center of rotation.

$$ \begin{aligned} 
  \boldsymbol{p} & = m ( h\,\boldsymbol{\omega} - \boldsymbol{c} \times \boldsymbol{\omega}) \\
  \boldsymbol{L}_{\rm COR} & = \mathrm{I}_{\rm COR} \boldsymbol{\omega} + m\,h\,(\boldsymbol{c} \times \boldsymbol{\omega})
\end{aligned} $$

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. Most physical quantities are relative (velocity, position, etc.). I am confused on which axis of rotation a free rigid body spinning/tumbling in the air in some arbitrary fashion is rotating about. Is there a "unique" axis of rotation? From the fixed reference frame (earth), is the unique, instantaneous rotational axis the screw axis (Mozzi axis)? The particular kinematic motion of a body spinning is determined by the initial conditions. Mozzi axis may not pass from the center of mass but we can describe rotation about the CM. There are choices for the rotation axis.

Comment: The axis is like a physical object. You can define its position relative to the coordinate system used as described above. At any instant, it is unique and finite or at infinity (pure translation). The initial conditions play no specific role here. At any instant, it is the motion (velocity) vectors that matter only. For a body constrained by a joint (like a hinge) the axis _is_ a physical object.

Comment: Thanks. @Ja72, you mention that the initial conditions play no role. But one body launched in certain way tumbles differently that an object launched in a different manner. The Mozzi rotation axis is unique at any instant... so how should I view the fact that, geometrically, it is possible to move the body from one configuration to the next via a translation+rotation about any arbitrary point? If the point is arbitrary, then the axis of rotation is arbitrary even if the angular velocity is the same for any point about which the rotation happens....

Comment: A free floating body will always have the rotation axis either on the center of mass, or co-moving with the center of mass.  I still don't understand the question. The rotation axis is an idealization that helps describe the motion and from one instant to the next it might change rapidly. The location of the axis doesn't have to be a smooth function. its like the contact point of a body that can jump around.

Comment: Sorry again. for example, an object can rotate about a fixed axis to which it constrained to. All the points on  the fixed axis have zero velocity relative to the fixed reference frame. In the case of a spinning free body, I envision an imaginary line ( the rotation axis) on which those rigid body points all moving with the same velocity (nonzero relative to the fixed reference frame) are found while all the other rigid body points rotate around them. It think the screw axis is that unique axis at every instant but it does not coincide with the CM axis.

Comment: @BrettCooper - yes everything you stated above is correct, except the screw axis _can_ coincide (go through) the CM if the body does not have any linear momentum (CM does not move).

Comment: Hello Ja72, can I ask you some further clarification on this same matter of rotational axis? I started a different thread to be more specific

Comment: I still remain a little doubtful: I get that at any instant of time t there is a unique instantaneous rotational axis, the screw axis, with several properties. All points sitting on the screw axis have identical velocity parallel to the screw axis itself. However, according to the equation $v_P(t)=v_O(t) +\omega(t) \times (P-O)$, a point $P$ of the body can rotate about an axis passing through the arbitrary point O and this axis is not the screw axis. Since $O$ is arbitrary, then the rotation axis is also arbitrary and there are many about which I can see point $P$ rotating...Is that wrong?

Comment: @BrettCooper - The point $O$ also has linear velocity $v_O$, and it is _not_ a rotation axis unless this velocity is parallel only. The velocity transformation law describes a helical vector field around the rotation axis, defined precisely as the locus of points whos linear velocities all line up along the rotation axis.

Comment: Thanks ja72. Do you mean that the velocity $v_O(t)$ may not be parallel to the screw axis or to the angular velocity $\omega(t)$? The instantaneous velocity field does not result in a helical screw. But the way I read the term $\omega(t) \times (P-O)$ is as a rotation of point $P$ about point $O$ implying that there must be a rotation axis and $O$ is a point on it and this axis is parallel to $\omega(t)$. The screw axis is parallel to $omega(t)$ but its points and its points have velocity parallel to the screw axis. Point $O$ is on a rotation axis but its velocity is not parallel.

Comment: Sorry, I did follow this. You can express any three components of $\vec{v}$ as $$\vec{v} = h \vec{\omega} + \vec{r} \times \vec{\omega}$$ by evaluating the screw axis position vector $\vec{r} = (\vec{\omega}\times \vec{v}) / \| \vec{\omega} \|^2$ and the scalar pitch $h = (\vec{\omega}\cdot\vec{v}) / \| \vec{\omega} \|^2$.

Comment: Thank you. I did not have that equation. It remains that we if look at the equation $v_P(t) = v_O(t) +\omega(t) \times (P-O)$, wouldn't you say that point $P$ must rotate about the arbitrary point $O$ which implies that there is an axis (of rotation, not the screw axis necessarily) passing through $O$? I am looking for validation on that concept. Thanks!

Comment: @BrettCooper - all this equation states, is how the velocity varies from point to point. It does not describe the _motion state_ of a rigid body unless additional restrictions are placed on $\vec{v}_O$. That was my point. The equation itself isn't insightful on its own, but rather a result of the assumption that _there exists a rotation axis somewhere in space_ and that the general motion of a rigid body can be described by such axis, in addition to a parallel translation.

Comment: Thanks again. Let's see if we can put this topic to sleep :) So you are saying it is more about the assumption that "there exists a rotation axis somewhere in space"...But why is my interpretation of the term $\omega(t) \times (P-O)$, that the point $P$ is rotating about $O$, wrong? The distance $r = (P-O)$ is from$O$ to $P$ which is moving with velocity $v_P(t)=\omega r$ around point $O$...

Comment: @BrettCooper - because if $v_O(t)$ in $v_P(t) = v_O(t) +\omega(t) \times (P-O)$ isn't zero or parallel then, $O$ does not belong to the rotation axis.

Comment: So, let's assume that point $O$ is not on the screw axis because of the two reasons you mention. If we sat on point $O$ at time $t$, would we see the rest of the points "rotate about us" and appear to travel along circular segments? Or not at all? What if we sat on a point $Q$ that is on the screw axis? I think we would surely see other points trajectory as being segments of a circle.
Is it correct to state the the velocity of points on the screw axis have the smallest magnitude, at time $t$, compared to magnitude of the velocities of all other points? Or is that not necessarily true?

Comment: If you sit at _any_ point, all other points are revolving around you (by definition). But it only makes sense to use internal reference frames because then the equations of motion work out fine. In addition, any rotation + translation = rotation about some other axis. So I really don't see what is it you do not understand.

Comment: I get that there is a unique $\omega(t)$ vector and which is a free vector (every point rotates by the same angle at the same rate). I get that there is a unique instantaneous rotational axis (the screw axis) parallel to $\omega(t)$. I have been perplexed, so far, by the fact that in dynamics the center of rotation is conveniently chosen to be the center of mass CM and not the screw axis leading me to think that we can choose to view rotation happen about any arbitrary rotational axis (in particular the one passing through CM) and not just the screw axis.

Comment: Also, what does it mean that "any rotation +translation= rotation about some other axis"? Where can I learn more about that? Can you elaborate on that just a bit?

Comment: @BrettCooper - please [read this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/249816/392) for the choice of CM vs. rotation axis (and links therein). You are free to choose any point of reference, just that the CM makes things simpler. Also look up [Chasle's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chasles%27_theorem_(kinematics)) for your reference on kinematics.

Comment: Thank you ja72. The CM simplifies dynamics equations a lot. The link mentions that the CM is often chosen for rigid body motion description, but this is not an obliged choice. So in dynamics it seems more useful to use the CM as the point about which the body is rotating instead of the screw axis. This goes back to my point of confusion, i.e. we can see the body as rotating about any axis (as long as that axis is parallel to $\omega$). Among these axes, we have the choice of the screw axis and the axis passing through CM...

Comment: Hello ja72, I was reading a thread https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/374832/rigid-body-rotation-and-translation-about-an-arbitrary-axis

Comment: I was reading the thread https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/374832/rigid-body-rotation-and-translation-about-an-arbitrary-axis: for a rolling disk, the motion has  two different descriptions (both from the same fixed earth reference frame): pure rotation about contact point (zero velocity) OR as a translation of CM+rotation about CM. In the 2nd description, the CM is the ICR through the entire motion. In pure rotation, the ICR is a point on the body but changes with time. hope it is correct. Does the ICR need to always have the smallest velocity (zero in 2D and minimum in 3D motion)?

Comment: @BrettCooper - in 2D by definition the _centre_ of rotation has zero velocity. in 3D the requirement for the _axis_ of rotation is that it has velocity only parallel to the axis. Think of the motion of a screw which rotates, but the center of the screw is in pure translation. That is the general motion of a rigid body. _Any motion_ in 3D can be decomposed into a rotation about an axis, and a parallel translation along the same axis.

Comment: @BrettCooper - you really should have posted this as a new question and not as a comment, in order to a) let the entire community an opportunity to answer, b) give proper attribution to the accepted answer and c) make it discoverable for others that might have the same question.

Comment: I will. thank you for responding. Not surprisingly, I have some more comments :)

Comment: @BrettCooper - I was hoping you are going to say you have more questions and that you are going to post them soon.

Comment: Hello, just to summarize: the various points of a freely moving rigid body have their own velocity but all share the same $\omega$. Knowing the velocity of a certain point and $\omega$, we can find the velocity of any other point. If that "certain point" has a velocity instantaneously parallel to $\omega$, then the inst axis of rotation passes through that point.

Comment: @user34203 - yes. That was a super nice summary there. And the for a rigid body, there _always_ exist such axis, even it is at located @ infinity as in the case with pure translation.

Comment: Thank you ja72! But if the actual axis of instantaneous rotation is the one I described, i.e. parallel to $\omega(t)$  and passing through the point with its entire velocity parallel to the vector $\omega(t)$, why is the center of mass (C.O.M) more often chosen in dynamics problems as the center of rotation if the C.O.M is indeed not the actual ICR...

Comment: That is an excellent question. The quick answer is that the center of mass is special point that simplifies the equations (removes cross dependency between linear and angular parts) and that the center of mass is pre-defined from the geometry and does not depend on the dynamics of the problem.

Comment: @user34203 see the update to answer now which expands a bit more on the above comment.

Comment: Thank you. I agree that using the C.O.M. simplify equations involving forces, torques, and energy...So using COM seems better than focusing on the ICR at the end of the day... Unless the ICR and the instantaneous axis offer some advantages that I am missing. Would it be still appropriate to call the C.O.M, or any other point, a "center or rotation" even if it is not the ICR? I believe that the line connecting the COM to any point on the object is also perpendicular to the point's velocity vector, unless I am mistaken. All points seem to orbit around the COM as well even if it is not the IRC...

Comment: You have a single instant center of rotation, but you might have multiple relative rotation axis. For example if a coin is rolling on a moving body, the relative rotation center is  at the contact, but the ICR might be somewhere else. There is an elegant geometry that connects rotation centers. Refer to [this wikipedia article section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instant_centre_of_rotation#Relative_center_of_rotation_for_two_contacting_planar_bodies) that I authored. In the study of robotics and mechanism analysis the centers of rotation are critical in understanding the behavior of systems.

Comment: I see, thanks. So, kinematically, instantaneous helicoidal motion is the most general combination motion for a rigid body. It consists of translation and rotation about the instantaneous axis (which can vary from instant to instant). The rigid body moves at every instant through a sequence of helicoidal movements. As you mention, all points different from the center of instantaneous rotation can be "relative rotation points. The COM is one of them and is surely useful. I guess motion w.r.t. COM is not helicoidal? Isn't the COM's velocity parallel to the rotation axis passing through the COM?

Comment: It is rigid bodies that move in a screw motion, which means that _all_ points riding along the body also move in the same fashion. This means that the velocity of _each_ point has two parts. One parallel to the rotation axis, and one along the "hoop" direction. $$ \boldsymbol{v} = \boldsymbol{v}_{\parallel} + \boldsymbol{\omega} \times \boldsymbol{r} $$

Comment: yes, thanks for the correction: all points move in a helical fashion around the points sitting on the instantaneous axis of rotation. The points sitting on the inst. axis of rotation do not exhibit helical displacement around the other ones...

Comment: Hello again, Ja72. I don't leave alone the topic of the instantaneous axis of rotation.  As mentioned, for a hinged object, the hinge has zero velocity and always corresponds to the instantaneous axis of rotation. But we could arbitrarily pick ANY other axis passing through any point as long as it is // to omega(t), and view the hinged object as rotating about that axis. Could you remind me the advantages we get from describing the instantaneous rotation about the screw axis instead of about the axis through the center of mass (popular choice) or any other axis passing through any other point?

Comment: Often is advantageous to consider points that have simplified kinematics (pivot points, roll centers, etc) because exactly they simplify the kinematics of the problem. A pivoted body shares linear velocity with its parent object at the pivot point. On the other hand, dynamics are simplest when considering the center of mass. Thus the difficulties in dynamics, where you need kinematics and dynamics at the same locations, so you are forced to transform either the torques or the acceleration to make everything work together.

Comment: Thank you as always! Have you ever used software/hardware that experimentally tracks and measure the screw axis and its points? If so, it would be great to know. We know the trajectory of the CM is a clean parabola for free moving objects. The trajectory of the screw axis of CIR is probably more complicated than a parabola. In the case of a rolling object, the instantaneous motion is rotation about CM+translation with CM. Using the CIR, the motion is simply a pure rotation. It seems that CIR, in 2D, and screw axis in 3D, are great for situations with mechanical links. Thanks!

Comment: @BrettCooper - due to conservation of momentum, the percussion axis is conserved in time. That would be interesting to visualize. On the other hand the motion screw axis is driven often by the kinematics, and the force line of action by the application loads.